# Use for Development button in Xcode 6.1 - already know window has changed

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

Apple says I can enable a device for development by clicking "Use for Development in Xcode's Device windos" The problem is that the button Use for Development is missing too. What am I doing wrong? I'm using Xcode 6.1

Comment: What do you see for your device in Xcode's Devices window?

Comment: everything but this button. I see the phone info, device information and etc but the button is missing

Comment: Since we can't see what you see, saying you see "everything" is a bit too vague. Be specific.